# Adding "web version link" in email by sendgrid

Tags: email, web, sendgrid

How do I add a link to a web version of my sendgrid emails like "having trouble reading this email, click here"?

**[EDIT]**
I use a php sendgrid library 
include "sendgrid-php-master/SendGrid_loader.php";

And I use this code and it doesn't work :

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
....
$mail->setHtml('<a href="[weblink]">View this email in your browser</a><br />'.$sg_html_code);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that SendGrid terminated the [weblink] and [unsubsribe] in **2017** (30/09/2017). You need to migrate with the new migrating toolkit.

Read more from SendGrid [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Legacy_Newsletter/Legacy_Newsletter_Features/tags.html)

Comment: That link suggests that the [weblink] tag still works?

Answer (score 9):

Just to confirm what Lirianna said, here you have the answer from Sendgrid support team to the same question:

> Using [Weblink] will only be supported when using our Marketing Campaigns tool. To use this in a transactional template, you would need to create and host that link yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It's the latter half of 2021 and I tried using `{{Weblink}}` (capitalisation important) and it works just fine for me using the Dynamic Templates option.. YMMV

Comment: An update to this.. it seems to only work if sent from Sendgrid's template editor, it doesn't actually work when sending real emails ‍♂️

Comment: by any chance did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same problem. Template editor's weblink works but it doesn't work when you send the actual email

Comment: No, this is no longer supported by Sendgrid if you're using dynamic templates.

Comment: @keithl8041 by any chance did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: Nope - it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official SendGrid documentation {{Weblink}} is available.
Refer: [SendGrid docmentation link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/weblink)